# Is there a substrate node that contains pallet-contracts and uses instant seal consensus?

Tags: smart-contract, consensus, pallet-contracts, substrate-contracts-node

I've seen [instant seal mentioned](https://youtu.be/uhkV0jAcWDY?t=392) as a way to get transactions sealed by the substrate node upon receipt.

I also know that moonbeam have this [in their node](https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam/commit/e018d429c027a0e95bd504dd7204881ba1c8d7b2).

Is there a substrate node that includes `pallet-contracts` and also implements instant seal?

If not, is it possible to modify the [substrate contracts node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/) to include this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The substrate contracts node [already uses instant seal](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/pull/42). Just update to the [latest version](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/releases).

Comment: Thanks, I guess the last time I used it was a while ago!

Comment: Is it a good idea to use instant seal for production? (for example, if I expect there are infrequent transactions in my custom solo chain)