# Manipulate block timestamp for ink! integration tests?

Tags: ink, smart-contract

I'm using `redspot` for integration tests. I have some contracts features involving with block timestamp. How can I manipulate the block timestamp in `substrate-contracts-node`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this via an existing method in an *integration test* as none exists but there is a workaround for *ink unit tests*.

The [test environment increases the block timestamp by a known amount each block](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/34bd952e3a632f26d7c946e537c3947e2327b3fc/crates/engine/src/test_api.rs#L223-L227):

```
    /// Advances the chain by a single block.
    pub fn advance_block(&mut self) {
        self.exec_context.block_number += 1;
        self.exec_context.block_timestamp += self.chain_spec.block_time;
    }
```

This means you will be able to determine the `block_timestamp` if you know the number of blocks that have passed. The `substrate-contracts-node` does not auto produce blocks in its default setup. It only produces blocks when it receives a transaction (this is known as [instant seal](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/1830/380)). Therefore, if you begin your test at block `X` at `block_timestamp_start` and you have issued `5` transactions by the end of your test, the `block_timtestamp_end` could be calculated by something similar to this:

```
block_timestamp_end = block_timestamp_start + 5 * chain_spec.block_time
```

Block timestamp could therefore be manipulated to a known value using the same process.

Comment: Where does the `chainspec.block_time` comes from? I thought that the timestamp of each block is the `now()` timestamp.

Comment: Hi @forgetso, can you please check my comment. Tks

Comment: Apologies Daniel, I was referring to the ink unit test environment but I now see that you are looking to run integration tests. The solution above will not work for integration tests and I've highlighted this

Comment: The reason why I used integration test is because the contracts needs cross-call to another contracts. AFAIK, we can't do this in `unit test`. To be more specific, we actually re-implement UniswapV2 in ink!. We have a pool contract that depends on two psp22 tokens contract. Is there a way to mock these two psp22 token contracts in unit tests? Tks alot @forgetso

Comment: Cross contract calls are not possible in ink unit tests currently. If you need to use block timestamps in integration tests you will have to setup your contract data so that the timestamps reflect the test outcome you require. You won't be able to manipulate the timestamps of blocks without manually editing the database or switching the chain data between tests.

Answer (score 3):

The Timestamp pallet has a helper function for tests and benchmarks called `set_timestamp`:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/timestamp/src/lib.rs#L283

```rust
/// Set the timestamp to something in particular. Only used for tests.
#[cfg(any(feature = "runtime-benchmarks", feature = "std"))]
pub fn set_timestamp(now: T::Moment) {
    Now::<T>::put(now);
}
```

This may be what you are looking for, at least within writing integration tests on a Substrate node.

Comment: Tks for the suggestion. I'm trying to find a solution that can set the timestamp from the client as part of the test. It should behave as `evm_increaseTime` rpc supported in `hardhat` node.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a [custom RPC](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/custom-rpcs/) that can be called by the JS environment. This custom RPC call could make use of the Timestamp pallet, as suggested by Shawn.